# Weird variable setting in python

Tags: python

I'm currently doing tutorial for django-rest-framework.
I've noticed something weird in it, I'm not sure if it is specific for Django or whole Python. Please look at code below:

```
linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False
```

It looks like shortened version of conditional instruction, but what is name of that operation? I can't find any specific information about it.

`lineos` is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it like

```
linenos = (self.linenos and 'table') or False
```

Which returns `'table'` if `self.linenos` is trueish, and `False` otherwise, due to the way that and and or are evaluated.

In modern Python we would write that using the ternary expression as

```
linenos = 'table' if self.linenos else False
```

Answer (score 0):

It is tri conditional flow
**If self.linenos is true it assigns table to linenos or else False**
*we can also chain this flow for multiple conditions*
**This is just like var=condition1?12:3 in most other languages**